# database configuration error - though I've set the settings and added the file

Tags: cakephp

If you were to browse to my website you would see I have database connection issues. I get CakePHP's error message telling me the file is missing. I've checked several times and everything I'm using cakePHP3. I  must have screwed up sonewhere, but I don't want to start all over again If you were to look at my code:

```
    <?php
/**
 * This is core configuration file.
 *
 * Use it to configure core behaviour of CakePHP.
 *
 * PHP 5
 *
 * CakePHP(tm) : Rapid Development Framework (http://cakephp.org)
 * Copyright (c) Cake Software Foundation, Inc. (http://cakefoundation.org)
 *
 * Licensed under The MIT License
 * For full copyright and license information, please see the LICENSE.txt
 * Redistributions of files must retain the above copyright notice.
 *
 * @copyright     Copyright (c) Cake Software Foundation, Inc. (http://cakefoundation.org)
 * @link          http://cakephp.org CakePHP(tm) Project
 * @package       app.Config
 * @since         CakePHP(tm) v 0.2.9
 * @license       http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php MIT License
 *
 * Database configuration class.
 * You can specify multiple configurations for production, development and testing.
 *
 * datasource => The name of a supported datasource; valid options are as follows:
 *      Database/Mysql      - MySQL 4 & 5,
 *      Database/Sqlite     - SQLite (PHP5 only),
 *      Database/Postgres   - PostgreSQL 7 and higher,
 *      Database/Sqlserver  - Microsoft SQL Server 2005 and higher
 *
 * You can add custom database datasources (or override existing datasources) by adding the
 * appropriate file to app/Model/Datasource/Database. Datasources should be named 'MyDatasource.php',
 *
 *
 * persistent => true / false
 * Determines whether or not the database should use a persistent connection
 *
 * host =>
 * the host you connect to the database. To add a socket or port number, use 'port' => #
 *
 * prefix =>
 * Uses the given prefix for all the tables in this database. This setting can be overridden
 * on a per-table basis with the Model::$tablePrefix property.
 *
 * schema =>
 * For Postgres/Sqlserver specifies which schema you would like to use the tables in. Postgres defaults to 'public'. For Sqlserver, it defaults to empty and use
 * the connected user's default schema (typically 'dbo').
 *
 * encoding =>
 * For MySQL, Postgres specifies the character encoding to use when connecting to the
 * database. Uses database default not specified.
 *
 * unix_socket =>
 * For MySQL to connect via socket specify the `unix_socket` parameter instead of `host` and `port`
 *
 * settings =>
 * Array of key/value pairs, on connection it executes SET statements for each pair
 * For MySQL : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/set-statement.html
 * For Postgres : http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/sql-set.html
 * For Sql Server : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190356.aspx
 */
class DATABASE_CONFIG {

    public $default = array(
        'datasource' => 'Database/Mysql',
        'persistent' => false,
        'host' => 'localhost',
        'login' => 'username',
        'password' => 'password', // db credentials removed
        'database' => 'database_name',
        'prefix' => '',
        //'encoding' => 'utf8',
    );

    public $test = array(
        'datasource' => 'Database/Mysql',
        'persistent' => false,
        'host' => 'localhost',
        'login' => 'user',
        'password' => 'password',
        'database' => 'test_database_name',
        'prefix' => '',
        //'encoding' => 'utf8',
    );
}
```

I don't know why Cake is not recognizing my file. I have the file placed properly in the directory it should be in. I remember trying to make the app work on shared hosting and that is how my Cake 2 thing might have been introduced. I'm stuck, guys.

Comment: You traying to use  CakePHP  2 db config file in CakePHP 3?  Read http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/database-basics.html#database-configuration

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't sure what the problem was!

Comment: @Salines you should make that an answer (explaining the difference in your answer).